# What is the efficient way to query subset of a joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is somewhat like this

```
SELECT TableA.Column1
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.ForeignKey = TableB.PrimaryKey
LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableC.PrimaryKey = TableB.ForeignKey
WHERE TableC.SomeColumn = 'XXX'
```

In the above case Table A and Table B are large tables (may contain more than 1 million rows), but Table C is small, with just 25 rows.

I have applied indexes on primary keys of all the tables.

In our application scenario, I need to search in TableC for just two conditions, `TableC.SomeColumn = 'XXX'` or `TableC.SomeColumn = 'YYY'`.

My question is what is the most efficient way to do this. A straight join does work, but I am concerned about joining with all the rows in TableB, just to pick a small subset of it, when joined in Table C.

Is it a good approach to have an indexed view?

For example,

```
CREATE INDEXED VIEW FOR TableB 
JOIN TableC ON TableC.PrimaryKey = TableB.ForeignKey
WHERE TableC.SomeColumn IN ('XXX', 'YYY'))?
```

Answer (score 0):

You `where` clause undoes the outer join, so you might as well write the query as:

```
SELECT a.Column1
FROM TableA a JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.ForeignKey = b.PrimaryKey JOIN
     TableC c
     ON c.PrimaryKey = b.ForeignKey
WHERE c.SomeColumn = 'XXX';
```

For this query, you want indexes these indexes:

- `TableC(SomeColumn, PrimaryKey)`
- `TableB(ForeignKey, PrimaryKey)`
- `TableA(ForeignKey, Column1)`

You can create an indexed view.  That would generally be the fastest for querying.  However, it can incur a lot more overhead for updates and inserts into any of the base tables.

Answer (score 0):

I typically only use a `JOIN` when I need to `SELECT` or `GROUP` on the data, not when using it as a predicate.  That said, I would be very curious to see if Gordon's answer or this one performs better.

I would also suggest getting in the habit of using alias' when referencing your tables, its less typing, and makes your code easier to read.

I would test and compare execution times:

```
SELECT A.Column1
FROM TableA A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM TableB B
              WHERE A.ForeignKey = B.PrimaryKey
              AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                          FROM TableC C
                          WHERE C.PrimaryKey = B.ForeignKey
                          AND C.SomeColumn = 'XXX'))
```